# Thread 6 AQClient error

Tags: iphone, ios, runtime-error

[image]

In costructor i am init the lame and in other function calling lame's function lame_encode_buffer_interleaved . but for this getting error

> Thread 6 AQClient: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Comment: I think `lame`,`mp3_buffer` will not be allocated.

Comment: i have not allocated lame and mp3_buffer anywhere

Comment: Why did you commented the `lame_init()` ?

Comment: in constructor as u see it down in image i have writen that code